# Salesforce internal server error after trying to edit Chatter Answer Zone

Tags: community, sandbox, chatter-answers, zone

I developed Community application on Developer edition org and now I'm trying to configure the application in fresh Sandbox which was refreshed from Production a day ago.

My application is used Answer zone.

The Sandbox has own zone which is used in other application which are on Production phase. Before deployment I had ability to edit the existing zone.

[image]

But after deployment I can't edit any of these because when I clicked edit link I got an error:

[image]

I've deactivated the existing zone

[image]

but still have got the same error.

Does anyone know how to fix this error or enable **Show In Portal** via metadata ot some hack?

Thanks.

GACK:
Error ID: 1378957425-100595 (-1064305567)